# Printing dynamic value in C

Tags: c

I have a program that transfers a file written in C. I wanted to give the user some feed back on how much bytes and/or percentage has been transferred. My codes does something like this:

Transferring......100 bytes.
Transferring......200 bytes.
Transferring......300 bytes.
Transferring......400 bytes.
Transferring......500 bytes.
Transferred Complete!!!

As you can see, if I transfer a large file it'll print a bunch of lines. Is it possible to have the number of bytes updates and change without printing another line?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Not with printf. Try the ncurses lib: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: As a rule of thumb it's best to include a snippet of the relevant code with your question. Makes answering it easier and probably gets you a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this generically in standard C - after all, the output of your program might be going directly to a line printer.

However, on many terminals you can print a `\r` character to return the cursor to the beginning of the current line (or print a number of `\b` backspace characters to erase characters one-by-one).

Answer (score 0):

Use `\r` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a win32 application, you can manipulate the position of the cursor with the `SetConsoleCursorPosition(HANDLE, COORD)` method to overwrite specific characters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025(v=VS.85).aspx